# Apache Ivy: Pointing to a repository manager

Tags: java, ant, configuration, ivy, artifactory

I'm trying to configure Ivy to play nicely with Artifactory (a popular repository manager) and need confirmation that I'm heading down the right path here.

I assume that once I have Artifactory configured correctly on my repository server, that I can just point Ivy to some directory under `ARTIFACTORY_HOME` and pass it the same information as I would an ordinary URL resolver. This way, Artifactory gets passed the info (what command to process, username & password, etc.) and takes over on the actual repositories behalf. (Thus, if credentials are wrong or if the user doesn't have permission to honor the request, Artifactory sends back a 404/etc.)

So to start with, if this is wrong, please correct me!

So here is what I'm thinking. In the Ant build for my project:

```
<ivy:settings url="http://my-repo-server.com/ivy/settings/ivy-settings.xml"/>

<target name="ivy-resolve">
    <ivy:configure host="http://my-repo-server.com/ivy"
        realm="ivy"
        username="developer" <!-- "developer" is read-only user configured in Artifactory -->
        passwd="38ur84u83j38y83u" <!-- encrypted password provided by Artifactory -->
        override="false"/>
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" conf="compile"/>
</target>
```

And then, in the (server-side) `ivy-settings.xml`:

```
<resolvers>  
    <url name="repo-server">
        <ivy pattern="http://my-repo-server.com/ivy/???"/>
        <artifact pattern="http://my-repo-server.com/ivy/???"/>
    </url>
</resolvers>
```

So when a developer's Ant build runs the `ivy-resolve` target, the Ivy client knows where to go to find the `ivy-settings.xml` file, and configures itself using the `developer` user and encrypted password that I set up in Artifactory.

The only problem is, I'm not sure what to specify for Ivy & Artifact patterns in the settings file? I assume I have to set them to some directory that is controlled by Artifactory, but I'm not sure what (in Artifactory my repo uses the default Ivy repo layout).

Also, am I violating Artifactory "best practices" by placing the settings file on the repo server like I did?  Should I place it inside some Artifactory-managed (hidden) directory? If so, where and why?

Ultimately, code samples help me learn fastest & easiest (I'm a graphical learner), so any programmatic nudges in the right direction are enormously appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think what you need to do is try to get it working, then when something doesn't behave the way you expect post a specific question here.  If you read the [faq] and [ask] you'll see that this broad type of question is off-topic.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback Jim but I don't think your argument holds here. Something isn't working - my Ivy/Artifactory configuration! And I have no idea how to get it working! This requires knowing what values to place inside the pattern elements in my settings file. I finished (that) main question by simply requesting any skilled Ivy/Artifactory veterans to also chime in if they think I'm not placing the settings file in the correct location. Nothing about this question is vague or broad.

Comment: do you understand how the ivy and artifact patterns work? i.e. do you have this working without using artifactory and are now trying to add artifactory to a working solution? The section you want is the patterns bit in here - http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/concept.html

Comment: Yes I have them working without Artifactory. But since I don't know where Artifactory stores the repos it controls, I don't know what the URL of the patterns should be.

Comment: all the answers appear to be in their documentation - http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Ivy